# Google Sign-In for Websites Automatical Sign-In

Tags: javascript

I integrated Google Sign-In on my website.

However, if I visit my website again without cleaning the history of the browser, it automatically signs in the website and moves to the redirected page.

If I sign out and go back to the sign in page, it does not automatically signs in, however, if I click the Google Sign-In button, it does not ask me my account and password and send me to the redirected page.

I want to make the browser stay at the sign-in page until a user clicks the Google Sign-In button. Also, I want it to ask a user her/his account and password every time.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you looking for https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Answer (score 0):

**Last Part**: **I want it to ask a user her/his account and password every time.** :
If user has authenticated the app (Give permission on first time), then it will not ask for username or password from next time that is 'Allow Access' page will not come. (Given User is also SignedIn in browser with same google account)

However if user is not signed in, then Google will ask to Sign in through pop up window.

**First Part** : Only cleaning the history will not help. Try clearing Cache of the browser (**Ctl-Shft-Del** shortcut).